# Mat-Icon not displaying for Edit Button

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I have a mat-icon button,however after adding [routerlink]="[/edit-job]" I am not able to view the button icon. Although I can see mat-tooltip and on clicking it redirects me to edit page but I am unable to viewe Icon.

Current Code for Mat-Button

```
 <button
        mat-icon-button
        [routerLink]="['/edit-job']"
        matTooltip="Edit Job"
      ></button>
```

However If I change my code to this I am able to view Icon properly

```
<button mat-icon-button (click)="editJob()" matTooltip="Edit Job">
            <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
          </button>
```

Can someone tell what am I doing wrong and how to fix it.
I am attaching a screenshot for better understanding.
[image: Snapshot of Screen]

Comment: In the first code snippet, you haven't added "<mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>" anywhere, so it won't show the edit icon as expected.

Comment: Thanks.. so silly of me .. and I was searching the issue for more than 5 hours

Answer (score 1):

as  @Sumit Vekariya said add `<mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>` to your button

Ex:

```
<button mat-icon-button [routerLink]="['/edit-job']" matTooltip="Edit Job">
  <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

As shown on the documentation you should add the import on app-module

https://material.angular.io/components/button/api

The import to add is :

```
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
```

And thats an example of material button :

```
<button mat-icon-button>Click me!</button>
```

Comment: That's not the right syntax of an icon button - ideally, the child element of `button[mat-icon-button]` should be a `mat-icon` element. If you want a text button, use the `button[mat-button]` or any of its other styles.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include `<mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>` inside the `<button>` tag for the first case too.